# AWS Data Migration Service (DMS) not moving identity, foreign keys, default values, indexes

Tags: amazon-web-services, sql-server-2014

I was able to clone one of my SQL Server database using the DMS. It copied clustered indexes, primary key definition etc along with the data.

However, it didn't not move/copy other constraints (identity, foreign key definition, default values) or any indexes.

I have generated / scripted out the indexes, default constraints and foreign keys, executed successfully. But is there a way to turn on the `IDENTITY` on respective columns ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figured out there is no way i can do this with AWS DMS as it do not import secondary/foreign keys, Indexes and Identity columns as well. You need to do it manually yourself by generating a script from SSMS or writing your own script.

Check this FAQ from Amazon:

Q. Does AWS Database Migration Service migrate the database schema for me?

To quickly migrate a database schema to your target instance you can rely on the Basic Schema Copy feature of AWS Database Migration Service. Basic Schema Copy will automatically create tables and primary keys in the target instance if the target does not already contain tables with the same names. Basic Schema Copy is great for doing a test migration, or when you are migrating databases heterogeneously e.g. Oracle to MySQL or SQL Server to Oracle. Basic Schema Copy will not migrate secondary indexes, foreign keys or stored procedures. When you need to use a more customizable schema migration process (e.g. when you are migrating your production database and need to move your stored procedures and secondary database objects), you can use the AWS Schema Conversion Tool for heterogeneous migrations, or use the schema export tools native to the source engine, if you are doing homogenous migrations like (1) SQL Server Management Studio's Import and Export Wizard, (2) Oracle's SQL Developer Database Export tool or script the export using the dbms_metadata package, (3) MySQL's Workbench Migration Wizard.

Comment: yes... 1.importing schema manually and then 2.running DMS worked for me with         ```"TargetTablePrepMode": "TRUNCATE_BEFORE_LOAD"``` option